# How i update only one column of mysql WebService SOAP in java

Tags: java, eclipse, soap

I have a SOAP WebService made ​​in java and estouc om problems in creating an Update code with it. The codes and tutorials that I am finding the Internet only shows how to update all fields in a table at once and does not allow the person to update one or more specific fields , wanted the help to be able to do this, wanted the webservice only atualizassem the fields "X id" which I send some value. Anyone know how to help me or have some stuff ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Well I have a function that updates the data of a particular user , the problem is when I want update a specific field I am forced to update all of the other ... I was wondering how do I be able to update only the fields that the User wants without being forced to change the information of others. Ps i don't know how to put code here